# Pivot table in Excel - How to group similar data together

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to analyze some data where players have ratings from about 1500-2900. I have no idea how to do this, I don't get `Excel` at all. I see I can use some formulas like sum and average but don't know how to make it do something specific. I want for example to count the number of players that are in the same group, where a group is represented by players which have a rating between 1600-1700 for example.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Pivot Table. In the row data you add the cell ratings. In the value section you can add the names or the cell ratings (again) it doesn't matter. But make sure you click on it and change the calculation from sum to count. The output is: by every rating value you can see the count of players... If you want to group you will need to do that in the datasheet (add a new column with a grouping criteria). Then create a pivot and instead of the ratings in the row data, you change it to the grouping criteria.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure how to add a column with a grouping criteria.. I don't care if I have to manually type all options but I really can't figure out how to do even that.. could you please explain how this should or could be done?